# Concatenation VHDL (2 8-bit vectors)

Tags: vhdl

I was just wondering, how could I concatenate two 8 bit vectors together into a 16-bit vector with odata_H having the MSB and odata_L having the LSB? Any help would be appreciated. The vectors are data points given off from an ADT7420 temperature sensor.

```
signal BCD:             std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal Bin_Temp:        std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal Bin_Acc:         std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal Buff_Temp:     std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal Buff_Acc:      std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal odata_L:         std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal odata_H:         std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal notEN:           std_logic;
signal odataT:          std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   begin
odataT <= odata_H & odata_L;
Bin_Temp <= odataT(8 downto 1);
notEN <= not(EN);
```

Comment: What part of `odataT <= odata_H & odata_L;` in your code is confusing?

Comment: Just problems with the synthesized design from this, I guess. DId not match (anywhere close) to my elaborated design. I made a separate block to make things look cleaner to concatenate the two vectors. Hope this works now.

Comment: Why not ask a question about the real problem?  Please provide a [minimal,  reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The `&` function has no issues in any tools i am aware of. The issue is likely in your code.

Comment: Does Vivado abstract things at all while undergoing synthesis? I don't know why there would be discrepancies between my elaborated design and my implemented design. My elaborated design looks like it would function perfectly, but the design that goes to my board has outputs that are not connected to the circuit. Also, it has completely done away with the block I did for concatenation. I extensively looked at the differences between the two block designs.

Comment: specifically my AN bits for the 7segs AN(7 downto 0) do not appear to be connected to the block I tied them to as an output (7segment serializer)

Comment: Please check that the missing block is not "optimized away". It seems as if the error is somewhere else. -- Please reduce your problem to a [mre], and then [edit] your question and add it to your post.

Comment: Is there a way to keep vivado from optimizing my code during synthesis, it's doing some nonsensical things.

Comment: It may be likely your code may be the cause of the synthesizer doing nonsensical things. Without a [mcve] and a specific problem statement your question may be off-topic. See [ask]. Consider simulating first.

Comment: Given synthesis problems, the first question is always "Did it work in behavioural simulation?". Until the answer is Yes, you can expect synthesis tools to do just about anything they like to your precious design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why in this case the concatenation apparently doesn't work. Nevertheless, another way of achieving it is by using the `resize()` function of the numeric_std library.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

[...]
odataT <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(odata_H), odata_L'length));
```

The concatenation `(odata_H, odata_L)` will be resized with a length of `length` (16 in this case).
Of course `unsigned` instead of `signed` is possible, if applicable.

Comment: See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), the bit **Answer [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions**, "Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... • ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem."  It's really not clear what the issue is here.